# How to do a resizable link a:hover in CSS

Tags: css

how can i make a dynamic resizable hover background just like this [page](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_37322/) in the navigation bar.
I want to know if it's done only with CSS or it involves javascript (which i don't know anything)

Comment: [Java or JavaScript?](http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html)

Comment: This particular one uses JavaScript; CSS doesn't have continuing states. It's possible to make a similar one using CSS3, however.

Comment: he probably means javascript.  Chenci it can be done with CSS only.

Comment: Also, I don't feel like I understand what you mean by "dynamic resizable hover background". The [carousel's red background](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_37322/wp-content/themes/theme1433/images/carousel.gif) or the background on [the navigation background](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_37322/wp-content/themes/theme1433/images/header.png) or... ?

Comment: What i mean is the red background that highlights when you point your mouse (hover). I'm interested in that, rather than the drop down menu. The problem is that you can't use a gif, because texts are in diferent size, so you would need like 6 gif of diferent size (and i want more categories in the navigation bar). That's what i mean dynamic resizable red background because you can use it to any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial on how to make a CSS drop down/expanding menu

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: As i was saying, i'm looking to make the red background appears when mouse-over the li item. Because the text has different characters (in which some are larger) i can't put a static background (like a red background)

Answer (score 0):

That navigation was done using CSS and javascript, but you can do it without javascript.

[CSS Sliding Doors Technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

[Creating dropdown menus using CSS w/ a sprinkle of javascript](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)

Should you want to look at the plugin used to create the animate effects (fade for example) on the navigation sub-menu's, it's called [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).

Comment: i'm interested in the red background (i just put it above)